# How to display alert dialog in running thread?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget

I want to display an alert dialog depending upon the property and when the user clicks on the OK button, call the function again to get updated values within the running process.

I have the following code:

```java
importingProgress = ProgressDialog.show(context, getString(R.string.progressNewsListTitle),
    getString(R.string.progressProjectListMessage), true);

new Thread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            app.SetOtherTaskRunning(true);
            Ib_clients client = db.Ib_clients_GetById(app.GetCustomerId());
            try {
                LogManager.WriteToFile("---------------- Getting News from Webservice :- " + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()) + "----------------");
                CommonFuctions.CreateXml(context, h, client, db, app.GetBookMonth(), app.GetBookQuater(), app.GetBookYear(), Constants.News, app.GetWebServiceLastSyncDate(Constants.ServiceType.NEWS.toString()), Constants.ServiceType.NEWS, null, null, null, null, null);
                Return reponse = null;
                do {
                    reponse = CommonFuctions.SendingRequest(context, handler, db);
                    if (reponse.type.compareTo("warning") == 0) {
                        h.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                                alert.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.information));
                                alert.setMessage("dsgdgd");
                                alert.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.logoutDialogOk), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                                    }
                                });
                                alert.show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } while (reponse.type.compareTo("warning") == 0);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //Log.d(Constants.TAG, e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (importingProgress != null) {
            importingProgress.dismiss();
            importingProgress = null;
        }
    }
}).start();
```

If response type is `warning`, then display a message to the user and if the user clicks the `OK` button , then call `CommonFuctions.SendingRequest(context, handler, db)` again to get updated values. Until we get a.response type of `warning` , we need to display an alert dialog to the user and call `CommonFuctions.SendingRequest(context, handler, db)` again.

Class to return:

```java
public class Return {
    public String type;
    public String msg;
    public boolean isSuccess;
    public int client_id; // for getting clientid from server 
    public int booking_id; // for getting bookingid form server
 }
```

Comment: Put your alertdialog code separate from the main thread. Try to run it on runonUIThread.

Comment: you can do it by using handler and its post method, because it has to run on UI thread

Comment: Please don't use tabs in your code. They'll probably break when other people edit your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use handler to display the AlertDialog because UI can be handled by the main thread only.

The other way is to use asyncTask for multiprocessing and then using the onPostExcecute() of asyncTask to display the AlertDialog

Please feel free to ask any further doubts.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your dialog as below in runonUIthread:

> ```
>  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
>                         @Override
>                         public void run() {
>                              AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);       
>                                     alert.setTitle(context.getString(R.string.information));
>                                     alert.setMessage("dsgdgd");
>                                     alert.setPositiveButton(context.getString(R.string.logoutDialogOk), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
>                                         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {      
>                                         }
>                                     });        
>                                     alert.show();
>                         }
>                  });
> ```

Comment: i can also use  handler.post() method to display alert dialog, but I want to stop loop while user did not click on ok button in alert dialog , otherwise loop continually run without stop on alert dialog .

Comment: @SushantBhatnagar I have still faced an issue.